# How do I modify a value in one thread and read the value in another thread using shared memory?

Tags: multithreading, rust, shared-memory

The following Python code creates a thread (actually a process) with an array containing two floats passed to it, the thread counts up 1 by the first float and -1 by the second float every 5 seconds, while the main thread is continuously printing the two floats:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from time import sleep

def target(states):
    while True:
        states[0] -= 1
        states[1] += 1
        sleep(5)

def main():
    states = Array("d", [0.0, 0.0])
    process = Process(target=target, args=(states,))
    process.start()
    while True:
        print(states[0])
        print(states[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I do the same thing using shared memory in Rust? I've tried doing the following ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bef8ec876ed06de21080f78449aa5fb8&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0.0]));
    let data = data.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
        data[0] = 1.0;
    });
    print!("{}", data[0]);
}
```

But that's giving a compile error:

```
error: cannot index a value of type `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<[_; 1]>>`
  --> <anon>:12:18
   |>
12 |>     print!("{}", data[0]);
   |>                  ^^^^^^^
```

And even if that'd work, it does something different. I've read [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/concurrency.html), but I've still no idea how to do it.

Comment: Also, you can fix the compile error like this: (I added a sleep() there for demo): https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=57e0b81ce1fc608dcf6a7622e934ea56&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: You might find the solution yourself if you stop confusing yourself by having three different, mutually shadowing variables called `data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not that far off! :)

Let's look at the compiler error first: it says that you are apparently attempting to index something. This is true, you want to index the `data` variable (with `data[0]`), but the compiler complains that the value you want to index is of type `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<[_; 1]>>` and cannot be indexed.

If you look at the type, you can quickly see: my array is still wrapped in a `Mutex<T>` which is wrapped in an `Arc<T>`. This brings us to the solution: **you have to lock for read access, too**. So you have to add the `lock().unwrap()` like in the other thread:

```
print!("{}", data.lock().unwrap()[0]);
```

But now a new compiler error arises: `` use of moved value: `data` ``. Dang! This comes from your name shadowing. You say `let data = data.clone();` before starting the thread; this shadows the original `data`. So how about we replace it by `let data_for_thread = data.clone()` and use `data_for_thread` in the other thread? You can see the working result [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a484e747bd465710152f601539befb37&version=stable&backtrace=0).

---

Making it do the same thing as the Python example isn't that hard anymore then, is it?

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0.0, 0.0]));
let data_for_thread = data.clone();
thread::spawn(move || {
    loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5))
        let mut data = data_for_thread.lock().unwrap();
        data[0] += 1.0;
        data[1] -= 1.0;
    }
});

loop {
    let data = data.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{}, {}", data[0], data[1]);
}
```

You can try it [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=521892e40599e9458c3c6e6af9e3abe6&version=stable&backtrace=0), although I changed a few minor things to allow running on the playground.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so let's first fix the compiler error:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0.0]));
    let thread_data = data.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut data = thread_data.lock().unwrap();
        data[0] = 1.0;
    });
    println!("{}", data.lock().unwrap()[0]);
}
```

The variable `thread_data` is always moved into the thread, that is why it cannot be accessed after the thread is spawned.
But this still has a problem: you are starting a thread that will run concurrently with the main thread and the last print statement will execute before the thread changes the value most of the time (it will be random).

To fix this you have to wait for the thread to finish before printing the value:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new([0.0]));
    let thread_data = data.clone();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut data = thread_data.lock().unwrap();
        data[0] = 1.0;
    });
    t.join().unwrap();
    println!("{}", data.lock().unwrap()[0]);
}
```

This will always produce the correct result.

Answer (score -3):

If you update common data by a thread, the other threads might not see the updated value, unless you do the following:

1. Declare the variable as volatile which makes sure that the latest update is given back to the threads that read the variable. The data is read from the memory block but not from cache.
2. Make all updates and reads as synchronized which might turn out to be costly in terms of performance but is sure to deal with data corruptions/in-consistency due to non-synchronization methods of writes and reads by distinct threads.

Comment: One does not declare variables as volatile in Rust. There's also no "synchronized" keyword, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You can do that by creating implicit locks on the objects for the threads which do reads,writes . Cannot believe that python does not provide monitor locking ability  Please see the following link for detail http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: You may wish to re-read the question to double check what language you are attempting to give an answer for.

Comment: It does not matter what language you use to programme, Every language does have the ability of locks. Multi-Threading is a common implementation for all languages. Anyways,I was considering Java while i answered.

Comment: Please do not assume that all languages do concurrent programming the same way. No one is expecting an answer here from someone who doesn't understand concurrent programming specifically in Rust.